# Angular Material Progress bar always showing 100%

Tags: angular, angular-material, progress-bar

I've ran into a strange problem with the Material Progress bar in Angular 10.  The progress bar shows at 100% even after settings it's value to something less:

Code is very simple in my component.html:

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="40"></mat-progress-bar>
```

And it renders ok, but shows at 100%

I can't see what I could be possibly doing wrong here.

Below is the content of my component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

in my app.module.ts file I am importing Material UI as follows:

```
import { MaterialModule } from './modules/material.module';
```

and the content of ./modules/material.module.ts is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';

const modules = [
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatProgressBarModule
];

@NgModule({
    imports: modules,
    exports: modules,
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

All other material modules work as expected, and as mentioned, the progress bar does render but it doesn't seem to take notice of the "value" attribute

Comment: When you provide a single line of code even we can't see what you are possibly doing wrong, more context is required. Please show what else you have in your typescript and template file.

Comment: Thanks, i've added more code to the my question.  There is very little going in my test, only material progress bar is present on the page.

Comment: If anyone comes here after googling custom snackbar with progressbar. Here is my implementation for the same: https://github.com/dheerajawale-svg/angular-snackbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this has been open for a little bit but I just ran across the same issue and it was driving me crazy. In my case I had defined a custom theme for material and only defined one color. So while the progress bar always looked to be 100%, at least in my case, it was because it was all the same color. Once I defined some lighter colors it worked as expected.

Comment: This also- turned out to be my issue, thanks for sharing your findings

Comment: this one of the classes you might need to change
::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
  background-color: #f0f0f0 !important;
}